# Which white wire is + and - on this automatic trash can?

Tags: wiring, trash-can

I am trying to change this automatic trash can from running on battery to wired. Someone successfully does it in this video with the same exact trash can I have. https://youtu.be/8Jc9dy3ohUA

One of the white wires has a long line of small red “X”s. The other has some letters and numbers in red like “awm” and “300V”

The X wire leads to the circuit board while the other one leads to the switch on the back of the trash can.

Which one do I screw into the + and - on my AC/DC adapter?

Comment: If you have a digital multimeter, you could just measure the voltage at the wires’ connection points to the switch and board with the battery inserted.

Comment: What the wires look like is immaterial.   "AWM" indicates the wire thickness inside, and "300V" is the maximum working voltage of the wire.  The red X's could be anything.   These are markings indicating the nature of the wire, not what the wire does in the circuit.  It's up to YOU to figure it out.  As stated above, without a voltmeter you're kinda flying blind.   I'm an electronic engineer but I don't have fingers than can detect voltages, so even with 25 years designing circuits I would still need a voltmeter here.  You definitely do too.

Answer (score 4):

In the video at the 3 minute mark, you can see that the meter is reading +6v with the red lead toward the inside of the bin. When the meter is moved to the right side of the video screen, the reading is -6v, indicating that the wires are twisted. This makes sense from a manufacturing standpoint, as the packs will be interchangeable.

You can perform the same test as in the video to confirm the polarity of the wiring. You can also examine the packs to determine which end of the battery contacts are positive (and negative) and extrapolate from there the wiring markings.

You will discover that the x-marked wire is consistently positive or consistently negative, but it's not an absolute that one can determine without testing. I have found black wiring with a white stripe. In one example, the marked wire was positive, in another, it was negative.

Comment: +1 For mentioning to examine the battery packs for + and -

Comment: Which wire is connected to the switch is also a good indication.  Its not 100%, but the positive wire is the one usually switched.